# Build an ActiveRecord query with multiple conditional clauses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

With ActiveRecord, you can build upon a query like so:

```
query = MyModel.where(value_one: true)
if (condition)
  query.where(value_two: true)
else
  query
end
```

However, I'm running into problems when there are multiple conditionals:

```
query = MyModel.where(value_one: true)
query.where(value_two: true) if condition_two
query.where(value_three: true) if condition_three
query
```

In this case, it'll only check that `value_one` is true. Interestingly, if I:

```
query = MyModel.where(value_one: true)
query.where(value_two: true)
query.where(value_three: true)
```

Then it'll check if `value_one` and `value_three` are true, but not `value_two`. Anyone understand why this is and how to get the query clauses to properly build upon each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you chain queries or scopes, ActiveRecord returns another Relation object with the additional conditions; it does not modify the original object. To modify a relation, you need to chain the query and assign the result, e.g.:

```
query = MyModel.where(value_one: true)
query = query.where(value_two: true) if condition_two
query = query.where(value_three: true) if condition_three
query
```

Note that the query is not actually executed until you attempt to extract the data, whether through `to_s`, `each`, etc.